# Suppose that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$. Show that if $Hg_1\subset Kg_2$ for some $g_1$ and $g_2$, then $H\subset K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have been trying to prove this, but I am stuck, here's my try:

Suppose $h\in H$. So, we have $hg_1\in Hg_1\subset Kg_2$. So, $hg_1\in Kg_2$.
$\implies hg_1=kg_2$ for some $k\in K$.

So, $h=kg_2g_1^{-1}$. Now I am stuck here. How, do I show that $h\in K$? I don't know if $kg_2g_1^{-1}\in K$ or not.

Any hint is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $H$ is a subgroup, the identity element $1 \in H$, and hence there exists $k \in K$ such that $g_1=kg_2$. Therefore, $g_2 g_1^{-1} = k^{-1} \in K$, as $K$ is a subgroup. Hence, $H \subseteq K g_2 g_1^{-1} \subseteq K$.

Comment: Thank you so much!